# Python OpenCV get bottom most value of mask

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I have an image from which I extract a colour into a mask as shown in the code below. The mask gives a black and white image. White being the colour I detect. The pixel value of white is 255 and black is 0.

I want to get the bottommost x and Y pixel of the white portion of the mask. How do I do this?
My code is as follows:

```
image = cv2.imread(FILENAME)

# THE COLOURS ARE IN RGB
lower_blue = np.array([50, 0, 0])
upper_blue = np.array([255, 50, 50])

# loop over the boundaries
#    for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
lower = np.array(lower_blue, dtype = "uint8")
upper = np.array(upper_blue, dtype = "uint8")

# find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
# the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy's `where` to search your mask for a specific value:

`np.max(np.where(np.max(img_binary,axis=1)==255)`